# Cyclic Group Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

If G is cyclic group of 24 order, then how many element of 4 order in G?
I can't understand how to find it, step by step.

Comment: You are given that $G$ is a "cyclic group of [order] 24".  Surely this is enough to identify $G$ up to isomorphism, and this allows you to explicitly determine which elements have order 4.  Have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Lemma:** If $o(g)=n$, then $o(g^k)=\dfrac{n}{gcd(n,k)}$.

Assume $G=\langle g \rangle$ and $o(g)=24$, notice that every element of $G$ has the form $g^k$ for some integer $k$, by lemma, $o(g^k)=\dfrac{24}{gcd(24,k)}$. Let $\dfrac{24}{gcd(24,k)}=4$, i.e., $gcd(24,k)=6$, we can easily conclude this only holds for $k=6$ or $k=18$. Hence there is only two elements in $G$ of order $4$, $g^6,g^{18}$.

Comment: It should be gcd, I make a mistake in the notation, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If $G=\langle a\rangle =\{a^0,a^1,a^2,\cdots,a^{23}\}$ then $$|a|=24\\|a^2|=k\to 24\mid2k\to12|k\to k=12.~\text{(because 12 is the least positive integer in this case)}\\|a^3|=k\to 24|3k\to8|k\to k=8.~\text{(because 8 is the least positive integer in this case)}\\|a^4|=k\to 24|4k\to6|k\to k=6.~\text{(because 6 is the least positive integer in this case)}\\|a^5|=k\to 24|5k,~\text{but} \gcd(24,5)=1\to 24|k\to\\ k=24.~\text{(because 24 is the least positive integer in this case)}\\
\vdots\\$$ By this mechanical way you can see why above **lemma** works.

Answer (score 1):

Any element of order 4 will generate a cyclic group of order 4. Inside any finite cyclic group, there is a unique cyclic subgroup of any order dividing the order of the group. Therefore, there is a unique group of order 4 inside this group of order 24 and every element of order 4 is inside this subgroup. In a group of order 4, the number of elements of order 4 is $\varphi(4) = 2$. So there are precisely two elements of order 4 in a cyclic group of order 24. In the usual representation of this as $\mathbf{Z}/24\mathbf{Z}$, these would be the elements $18$ and $6$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) A cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ has exactly $\;\varphi(n)\;$ generators.

(2) A cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ has exactly one unique subgroup of order $\;d\;$ for **any** divisor $\;d\;$ of $\;n\;$

Comment: Misleading.  A subgroup of order $d$ is not the same as an element of order $d$.

Comment: Nonsense, @hardmath . By (2) the OP knows there's one *unique* subgroup of order $\;4\;$ , and by (1) he knows there are $\;\varphi(4)=2\;$  generators of this subgroup, which obviously each has order $\;4\;$ . These were supposed to be *hints*, the OP **has** to fulfil stuff to make a round, complete answer of it: for example, I'd expect he already knows a subgroup of a cyclic groups is cyclic, etc. As in many other cases, he (andperhaps other) may prefer complete, chewed-up answers. Fine.

Comment: I can accept that your omission (of discussing elements of order n) was intentional, yet still find it misleading. Hints can be valid responses if requested, and I'll let the OP's wording ("step by step") speak for itself.  The broader audience for your Answer lies in the future Readership.

Comment: The "step by step", or "detailed answer, please", etc. are frequent requests here, and they don't *usually* get answered in that way, in particular not by veteran members. People usually assumes that a question like this **requires** some previous knowledge *and self work* by the OP, otherwise we could as well announce ourselves as "homework doers".